# What does this "ridiculous" mean?

Tags: meaning

> It was ridiculous how adorable you are.

A father said so to his daughter. Does this “ridiculous” carry a very strong feeling?

Comment: Ridiculous means laughable, absurd, comical, funny, hilarious, risible, droll, amusing, farcical, silly, ludicrous; not just negative, though most often to point *ridicule* at someone/thing. Ridiculously cute is common enough.

Comment: If it's accurately transcribed, I doubt that father is a native speaker. I can contrive a context where the opposite tense switch would be okay - *"It's [it **is**] ridiculous how adorable you **were**"*. But I can't begin to imagine how anyone could "validly" switch from past to present as cited.

Answer (score 4):

It's being used as an intensifier, that she's so cute that it's beyond plausible belief, a form of hyperbole. Compare to "It's crazy how adorable you are".

Side note, switching tense from past to present in the same sentence is generally a no-no.

Comment: Yes: it's virtually a paraphrase of 'You are madly adorable'. The substitution of an introductory pragmatic marker (emphasis / wow-factor marker'; classically labelled a 'comment clause') for an adjective-modifier (classically labelled an adverb) is interesting. 'Madly' probably carries too much semantic content (if at a distance – referencing the effect on observers) to be called a mere intensifier.